# how to replace posix_memalign on Solaris 10

Tags: c++, c, solaris, solaris-10

I have the following code which is part of the CRFsuite library. I've created an R wrapper for this library but the installation fails on Solaris 10 due to the fact that `posix_memalign` is not defined on Solaris 10.
How does the following code (part of https://github.com/bnosac/crfsuite/blob/master/src/crf/src/vecmath.h) need to be changed in order to compile correctly on Solaris 10? FYI installation error is shown [here](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-patched-solaris-x86/crfsuite-00install.html)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <memory.h>

#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__MINGW64__)
#include <malloc.h>
#else
#include <stdlib.h>
static inline void *_aligned_malloc(size_t size, size_t alignment)
{
    void *p;
    int ret = posix_memalign(&p, alignment, size);
    return (ret == 0) ? p : 0;
}
static inline void _aligned_free(void *p)
{
    free(p);
}
#endif
```

I've tried using some fixes that are made available [here](http://www.ccp4.ac.uk/dist/checkout/cctbx-phaser-dials-2015-12-22/boost/boost/log/detail/malloc_aligned.hpp), but failed miserably. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [memalign](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5168/memalign-3c.html#scrolltoc)()

```
... 
#elif defined __SunOS_5_10
    #include <stdlib.h>

    static inline void *_aligned_malloc(size_t size, size_t alignment)
    {
        return memalign(alignment, size)
    }
    static inline void _aligned_free(void *p)
    {
        free(p);
    }
#else 
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Using memalign was indeed the solution.